# Select third input box in a div with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a `div` called *foxcontainer* with a form inside, and inside the form each input box is in its own div, and all are without a name (except the first one, foxcontainer).

How do I select the 2nd (or 3rd) input box in that form with jquery so I can apply datepicker to it?

Comment: it's beem solved with find(eq)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As an example, you can use [`:eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) in selector:

```
$("#foxcontainer input:eq(1)");  // for 2nd input box
```

Another option is to use [`slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/):

```
$("#foxcontainer input").slice(2, 3);    // for 3rd input box
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/BU4Tf/

Answer (score 1):

you can get these by selectors, to get 2nd input you can try

```
var input2nd  =$('#foxcontainer input:eq(1)');
```

and for getting 3rd input you can try

```
var input3rd = $('#foxcontainer input:eq(2)');
```

or by using find function like

```
var $foxcontainer  = $('#foxcontainer');
var input2nd = $foxcontainer.find('input:eq(1)');
var input3rd = $foxcontainer.find('input:eq(2)');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the jQuery `:eq()` selector.
So:
`var second = $('#foxcontainer input:eq(1);`

Note that the counting start at 0, so the second is 1.